# Getting a list of Hotels availability information from booking.com connect API

Tags: api, sabre, ota

We do marketing solutions for our hotel clients. For that matter, we need to know their room availability. it would be easier to collect such information from booking.com cause all our clients use booking OTA, other than connecting API directly to each of them.

My question is: Can we get other hotels' availability from booking.com Connect API?
OR is there any other GDS solution we can get booking.com existing data, like Sabre?

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve what you want, Aggregators must be enabled in your PCC; in the documentation, there is a special field to enter the Aggregator number so that using this, you can retrieve the information from various hospitality sources.